# I cannot add a record to the resource file

Tags: c#, multilingual, resx

in this way I am adding a new record.

Error:

> ResX file Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. cannot be parsed.

```
ResourceWriter ren = new ResourceWriter(path);
DataContextDataContext db = new DataContextDataContext();
var result = db.MultiLanguages;
foreach (var item in result.ToList())
{
    ren.AddResource(item.key, item.en);
}
ren.Dispose();
ren.Close();
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkMEb.png)

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nq5tgz error message

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an `encoding` property in your resx file, at line no. 1:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>`

Also, use the `using` block to create the ResourceWriter instance. Something like this:

```
using(ResourceWriter ren = new ResourceWriter(path))
{
    DataContextDataContext db = new DataContextDataContext();
    var result = db.MultiLanguages;
    foreach (var item in result.ToList())
    {
        ren.AddResource(item.key, item.en);
    }
}
```